# Table rowcolor incomplete

Tags: tables, longtable

I am currently trying to fill a whole row from a longtable with color.

However, the collor filling does not make it to the end of the columns:

[image]

Any idea how can I fix this? Bellow I present the code.

Many thanks

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{p{8cm} p{3cm} p{1cm}}
        \caption{Calculation of estimated revenues for the first year of sales.} \label{tab:long} \\

        \hline \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Column}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Calculation}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Source/ Notes:}} \\ \hline 
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Column)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Calculation}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Source/ Notes:}} \\ \hline 
        \endhead

        \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
        \endfoot

        \hline
        \endlastfoot

        \lipsum[3]                                                                                                                                                                          & text text text                & Link 1                  \\ \hline         \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef}
        \lipsum[3] & text text text text       & Link 2                  \\ \hline
        \lipsum[3]                                                           & text text &                         \\ \hline
        \lipsum[3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    & 220,675 devices                   &                         \\ \hline
        \lipsum[3]                 &                         \\ \hline
        \lipsum[3] &                         \\ \hline
        \lipsum[3]                                                                                                             & 15\%                              &                         \\ \hline
        \textbf{Potential Market Volume:} \newline (Market volume = Number of devices purchased x Penetration rate)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & 33 101 devices                    &                         \\ \hline
        \lipsum[2]   & \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last column is wider than the specified size of `1cm`. This is caused by the `\multicolumn` in the header, which is of type `l` and therefore does not break the line. However, `rowcolor` uses the specified size and therefore does not color the full column.

When you increase the column width the issue is resolved - however it is better not to use multicolumns of size 1 and allow the main column type (`p{1cm}` in this case) to determine the column width.

Code:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{8cm} p{3cm} p{3cm}}
```

Result:

[image]